# How to implement final steps in pagination project?

Tags: php, css, pagination

I am doing my first pagination implementation to my site. I feel like I am very close and just confusing my logic or mistaking the placement or actual value of some variables.

Here is the code:

```
                    $pgsize_wave = 40;
                    $pg_wave = (is_numeric($_GET["p"]) ? $_GET["p"] : 1);
                    $start = ($pg_wave-1)*$pgsize_wave;
                    $waves = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `CysticAirwaves` LIMIT $start, $pgsize_wave");
                    $waves_total = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `CysticAirwaves`");
                    $waves_total = mysql_fetch_row($waves_total);
                    $waves_total = $waves_total[0];
                    $max_pages = $waves_total / $pgsize_wave;
                    $max_pages = ceil($waves_total/$pgsize_waves);


                    ?>



                    <div id="all_page_turn">
                             <ul>

                                <?php if($waves_total > 40 && $pg_wave >= 40) { ?>
                                 <li class="PreviousPageBlog round_10px">
                                     <a href="Airwave_build.php?id=<?php echo $pg_wave - 40); ?>">Previous Page</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <?php } ?>

                                 <?php if($waves_total > 40 && $pg_wave < ($waves_total-40)) { ?>
                                 <li class="NextPageBlog round_10px">
                                     <a href="Airwave_build.php?id=<?php echo ($pg_wave + 40); ?>">Next Page</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <?php } ?>

                             </ul>
                        </div>
```

To clarify any confusion, an airwave is a post from a user and I want to limit 40 per page. If it helps here is the query that pulls an airwave on the same page:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `CysticAirwaves` WHERE `FromUserID` = `ToUserID` AND `status` = 'active' ORDER BY `date` DESC, `time` DESC";
            $request = mysql_query($query,$connection);
            $counter = 0;
            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {

            $replies_q = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `CysticAirwaves_replies` WHERE `AirwaveID` = '" . $result['id'] . "' && `status` = 'active'";
            $request2 = mysql_query($replies_q,$connection);
            $replies = mysql_fetch_array($request2);
            $replies_num = $replies['COUNT(`id`)'];

            $counter++;
            $waver = new User($result['FromUserID']);
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You should explain what the problem is...

Comment: @Krtek - the problem is I am unable to get it to paginate

Comment: migrate to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *pseudo code* but hopefully explains the logic.

```
$total        = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `waves`
$currentPage  = 1  // changes through page parameter in URL
$wavesPerPage = 40
$totalPages   = ceil($total / $wavesPerPage)
$offset       = ($wavesPerPage * ($currentPage - 1)) + 1

$waves = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `waves` LIMIT $offset, $wavesPerPage");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($waves)) {
    echo $row['wave']
    …
}
```

To output the pagination links:

```
if ($totalPages > 1) {
    if ($currentPage > 1) {
        printf('<a href="waves.php?page=%u">Previous</a>', $currentPage - 1);
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
        $class = ($i == $currentPage) ? 'selected' : null;
        printf('<a href="waves.php?page=%1$u" class="%2$s">Page %1$u</a>', $i, $class);
    }

    if ($currentPage < $totalPages) {
        printf('<a href="waves.php?page=%u">Next</a>', $currentPage + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I undertand the logic. The problem is with the code itself. So pseudo code does not do me much good. I'm not wanting you to do it for me, maybe just correct what I have, or point out what is wrong with what I have.

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem? It's hard to advise anything concrete with such a vague error description and without being able to run the code myself (since I don't have your database). It seems to me that your offset calculation is off, for starters. I'd advise you tear down your script, implement the above code to have a working minimal example and build it up again from there. That, or try step by step debugging.

Comment: I think I am pretty close. I started over via your advice but still not doing the trick. Not only is it not limiting to 40 or paginating. The next link at the bottom of the page had a huge slew of "Page$i" links. Here is the most current code chunk. Thanks again for working with me on this. I want to mark this as the right answer. https://gist.github.com/9f92c5512ef324645342

Comment: OK, that was a bit too pseudo for you apparently. Fleshed it out a little more. The problem in your posted code is obviously that you're not looping through your `$result` resource. Also, you took the generation of pagination links too literally.